# how to target specific zip codes and show them different offers(banners) through target adobe tool?

Tags: javascript, adobe, aem

want to show different offers(banners) for different zip code through adobe target development tool. I dont want to specify in the tool, the zipcodes. Any suggestion will be helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to do it via Targeting rules you could potentially make the image come from a server side script I which you can pass the geo information via a token in the URL from the target side.